# Como posso fazer com que esse código apresente os 100 primeiros números pares não múltiplos de 10?

Tags: c, operadores, count

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
int main () { 
  int count; 
     for (count=0;count<200;count=count+2)   
     printf ("%d \t ",count); 
         if (count%10==0)
            {
             count++;  
            }
     getch(); 
return(0);  
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

tente da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

int main () {
int vezes = 0;
for(int count=0; vezes <= 100; count = count+2) {
    if(count%10 != 0) { //não multiplo de 10
        printf ("%d \t ",count);
        vezes++;
    }
}
```